# What libraries need to be linked for timer_create, timer_settime and other timer related functions

Tags: linux, timer, posix

Compiling a program on Linux that calls POSIX timer functions (eg: timer_create, timer_settime) returns errors such as:

```
In function `foo':
timer.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `timer_create'
timer.c:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `timer_settime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which library do I need to link?

Answer (score 32):

Compile it with `-lrt` option. It will get compiled.

Answer (score 8):

you can try `gcc -o mytemer mytimer.c -lrt`
it works for me like that but not in this order
`gcc -lrt mytimer.c -o mytimer`

Answer (score 4):

The -lrt forces the link but you have to have the real-time library in place before you can link to it.  Most of the time it's included automatically, but if not you'll need to install a real-time library using apt-get.  Then you will be able to link to it at the following (or similar) location:

`/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1`

If you're using codeblocks and for some reason -lrt doesn't include it, you can add the above library path & filename using the following menu sequence:

`Project->Build Options->Linker Settings->Link Libraries->Add`

Answer (score 3):

This should be documented in the man page. Given it isn't add `-lrt`.

Answer (score 2):

please try the following:

```
gcc -lrt
```